# Why is my while loop not working when no echo is put inside?

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop

I got a pretty simple code that will take 2 dates and loop my data until the end date is reached.

```
            $start = new DateTime($senddate);
            $now = new DateTime("NOW");
            $end = new DateTime ($end);


            //We check if starting date is >= now()
            if ($start->date <= $now->date){
                $start = $now;

            }

            $i=0;

            if ($frequency==4){
                while ($start->date <= $end->date) {
                    $calcdate[$i]=$start->date;
                    $start->modify('+1 month');
                    $i++;
                    echo '<!--';
                    print_r($start);
                    echo '-->';
                }
```

As you see there is a print_r inside the loop.
Everything work fine :)
BUT, if I remove it, then the loop never end .. I tried to add `if($i>50) exit;` without anymore success. I don't understand why this loop doesn't work when no pint_r is inside.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `while ($start <= $end)`

Comment: Humph ... In fact, not really, I still have bugs but I found out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error came from this line `$calcdate[$i]=$start->date;`
It seems that this gives somme unexpected behavior (in this case), I tried using `$calcdate[]=$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` which gave the expected results ... Don't know why  my script didn't worked with the date method. If anyone knows ..

Comment: Because there's no `date` property in DateTime objects?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a read of the [PHP DateTime manual](http://php.net/datetime), there is a lot of good information there that will help you with what you are trying to do.

As far as I can tell, you are trying to carry out an operation on a monthly basis between two dates that span the current date. There is a simpler way of doing it utilising the [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class.

Something like this:-

```
$start = new \DateTime('yesterday');// Just for demo purposes
$now = new \DateTime(); //No need for "now" as it is the default
$end = new \DateTime('+ 6 month');// again, for demo purposes
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');

if($now >= $start){ // you can do direct comparisons on DateTime objects
    $period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    foreach($period as $date){
        // Each $date is a DateTime instance that you can
        // operate on as you see fit, I have just var_dumped it out.
        var_dump($date);
    }
}
```

The above code can be seen working here http://3v4l.org/1I30E

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though, my error came from the ->date method/property as you said in your comment. using the format method solve it